# Spring showing application/*+xml instead of application/xml

Tags: xml, spring, google-chrome, spring-mvc

I have configured spring to resolve xml and json responses for our API as follows:

```
<!-- oxm integration -->
    <bean id="objectXmlMarshaller" class="org.springframework.oxm.xstream.XStreamMarshaller" />

<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.ContentNegotiatingViewResolver">
        <property name="ignoreAcceptHeader" value="false" />
            <property name="favorPathExtension" value="true" /> 
        <property name="mediaTypes">
            <map>
                <entry key="xml"  value="application/xml" />
                <entry key="json" value="application/json" />
            </map>
        </property>
        <property name="defaultViews">
            <list>
                <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.json.MappingJacksonJsonView" />
                <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.xml.MarshallingView">
                    <property name="marshaller" ref="objectXmlMarshaller" />
                </bean>
            </list>
        </property>
    </bean>
```

Unfortunately, spring returns xml responses with application/*+xml. It seems that chrome is not able to open such extensions and sends it to windows to open them (so rather than seeing the response on the browser, I have to open it via windows).

Does anyone know why it is returning application/*+xml instead of the configured application/xml?

If not, anyone know how to force chrome to display it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only way I found of solving this was to directly map the controller with the required:

```
@RequestMapping(produces = { "application/json", "application/xml" })
```

Too bad spring does not allow you to have a global definition.